# How to execute query SQL with LIKE when i have spaces in the string

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access

I created a database in Microsoft Access 2007 with the stock products of a company using an application buit in C # . I have a form to search for products by reference in the database but I am not able to obtain query results. The problem is that the column with the reference product has various spaces in the reference name:

[Column product reference in the database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FWeu5.png)

This is the code that I have to perform this query:

```
 private void Ref_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string connStr = (@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=Stock.accdb");
        string query = "Select * from product where product_ref like '%' + textBox_ref.Text + '%'";

        using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connStr))
        {
            using (OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, conn))
            {
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                adapter.Fill(ds);
                dataGrid_stock.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
            }



        }
    }
```

What I want is to introduce for example in the textbox: "VDS" or "NT" and the query return "VDS 15P M X" and "NIP FIN NT LL" respectively.

thanks in advance,

Comment: are you literally saying I want to enter into the textbox `"VDS" or "NT"` and you get both back?  basically you're trying to parse the text for orders of operation and "and/or"?

Comment: no not the bot. for example if i enter VDS the query should return the entire reference name. And the same for the others references. but just one at a time

Comment: Thanks it works AsheraH. And how can I improve my code to prevent SQL injection?

Answer (score 1):

Your query looks fine to me, I would only add a .Trim() to the end of textBox_ref.Text to prevent spaces from appearing between the search term and the % sign.

Answer (score 1):

Your query has "wrong" quotes. Try this:

```
string query = "Select * from product where product_ref like '%" + textBox_ref.Text + "%'";
```

Comment: Thanks works. And how can I improve my code to prevent SQL injection?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a proper way to execute SQL statement safely:

```
string connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=Stock.accdb";
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    connection.Open();
    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(
    "SELECT * FROM product WHERE product_ref LIKE '%@value%'", connection))
    {
        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("value", textBox_ref.Text.Trim()));
        SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            // Do whatever you want to do with the queried data
        }
    }
}
```

This snippet is ideal for preventing **SQL injections**. It uses so called **parameterized queries** to avoid security issues. Futhermore, it manages to close your database connection after the code is executed by itself.
`string.Trim()` erases leading or heading whitespaces. This prevents unexpected mistakes.